# One data member of object via pointer isn't coming through

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, datamember

It might be difficult to help with this problem because I have a lot of code and don't really know what's messing up my output.
The background info is that I'm writing a program that reads in lines of text from a file, parses the lines into tokens, then translates the tokens into commands to make different kinds of "sensors" (digital and analog).

There are two main problems that I'm having.  When a new sensor is made, the object is created and a pointer to the object is put in an array.  When the information for all of the sensors is printed, the print function of each object pointed to in the array is called.  This all works fine, but for some reason, the name of my sensor always comes up blank.  The correct token is parsed, and assigned to the correct part of the object, but somehow something is going wrong and all of the sensor names are listed as blank.

The other problem is similar.  There is another pointer array of sensorNode objects.  When I create two sensorNode objects and call their print functions via their array, they print fine.  When I add two more sensorNode object to the array though, and call it again, the info of the second two prints fine and the info of the first two is all garbage.  What is happening in there to lose those first two?

Here's my code, I know I put a lot, but I figured better more than less.

My main: (the object is created in the switch statement at the end for the "New Sensor" and "New Node" cases and printed in the "STATUS" case)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#include "definitions.h"
#include "system_utilities.h"
#include "sensor.h"
#include "sensor_node.h"


int main()
{
    int val;
    ifstream inFile;
    char line[MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH];
    char* token[MAX_TOKENS_ON_A_LINE];
    int numtokens;

    SensorNode* NodeList[MAX_NODES];
    sensor* SensorList[MAX_SENSORS];
    int numNodes = 0;
    int numSensors = 0;

    fillSystemCommandList();

    inFile.open("p6input.txt", ios::in);
    if(inFile.fail()) {
        cout << "Could not open input file.  Program terminating.\n\n";
        return 0;
    }
    do {
    inFile.getline(line, MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH);
    line[strlen(line)+1] = '\0';
    numtokens = parseCommandLine(line, token);
        int t;
        cout << "Number of tokens: " << numtokens << "\n";

                val = getCommandNumber(token[0]);

            switch(val) {
             case HALT:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n"; 
                    }
             cout << "Recognized command \"Halt\"";
             break;
             case STATUS:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
                    if (strcmp(token[1], "nodes") == 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                            NodeList[i]->print();
                        }
                    }
                    if (strcmp(token[1], "sensors") == 0) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < numSensors; j++) {
                            SensorList[j]->print();
                        }
                    }

             cout << "Recognized command \"Status\"";
             break;
             case TIME_CLICK:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
             cout << "Recognized command \"time click\"";
             break;
             case NEW_SENSOR:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }

                    if (strcmp(token[1], "digital") == 0) {

                        SensorList[numSensors] = new digitalSensor(token[2],convertFloatToValue(token[3]));
                    }
                    if (strcmp(token[1], "analog") == 0) {

                        SensorList[numSensors] = new analogSensor(token[2],convertFloatToValue(token[3]),convertIntToValue(token[4]),convertIntToValue(token[5]));
                    }

                    numSensors++;

             cout << "Recognized command \"New Sensor\"";
             break;
             case NEW_SENSOR_NODE:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }

                NodeList[numNodes] = new SensorNode(token[1], convertFloatToValue(token[3]), convertFloatToValue(token[4]), convertFloatToValue(token[5]), convertIntToValue(token[2]), convertFloatToValue(token[6]));

                    numNodes++;
             cout << "Recognized command \"New Sensor Node\"";
             break;
             case NEW_NETWORK:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
             cout << "Recognized command \"New Network\"";
             break;
             case ADD_SENSOR_TO_NODE:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
             cout << "Recognized command \"Add sensor to node\"";
             break;
             case ADD_NODE_TO_NETWORK:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
             cout << "Recognized command \"Add node to network\"";
             break;
             case SENSOR_COMMAND:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
             cout << "Recognized command \"Sensor Command\"";
             break;
             case UNDEFINED_COMMAND:
                    for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
                        cout << "Token "<< t << ": " << token[t-1] << "\n";
                    }
              break;
             default:
             cout << "Undefined Command";
             }
        for (t=1; t <= numtokens; t++) {
            free((void *)token[t-1]);
        }
            cout << "\n";

        cout << "\n";
    }
    while (val != HALT);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my sensor.h

```
#ifndef __Program_6__sensor__
#define __Program_6__sensor__

#include <iostream>

class sensor {
protected:
    char* SensorName;
    float energyDraw;
    int functioning;
    int onoff;

public:
    sensor(char*n, float pc);
    virtual void print();

    void setOK(int K);
    int getOK();
    void setOnOff(int n);
    int getOnOff();
};
//---------
class digitalSensor : public sensor {
    int reading;

public:
    digitalSensor(char*n, float pc);
    virtual void print();
    void setCurrentReading(int r);
    int getCurrentReading();
};

class analogSensor : public sensor {
    int Reading;
    int minRead;
    int maxRead;

public:
    analogSensor(char *n, float pc, int mn, int mx);
    virtual void print();
    void setCurrentReading(int r);
    int getCurrentReading();
};


#endif /* defined(__Program_6__sensor__) */
```

Parts of my sensor.cpp:

```
#include "sensor.h"
#include "definitions.h"
using namespace std;

//--------SENSOR CLASS------------//
sensor::sensor(char *n, float pc) {

    SensorName = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)+1);
    energyDraw = pc;
    functioning = WORKING;
    onoff = OFF;
}
void sensor::print() {
    cout << "     Sensor: " << SensorName;
    cout << "   Power Consumption: " << energyDraw;
    if (functioning == WORKING) {
        cout << "\n     Sensor is functioning correctly\n";

        if (onoff == ON) {
        cout << "     Sensor is On\n";
    }
        if (onoff == OFF) {
        cout << "     Sensor is Off\n";
    }

    }
    if (functioning == NOTWORKING) {
        cout << "     Sensor is not functioning correctly";
    }
    }
//*********DIGITAL SENSOR**********//

digitalSensor::digitalSensor(char *n, float pc) : sensor(n, pc){
    reading = 0;
}

void digitalSensor::print() {
    sensor::print();
    if (functioning == WORKING && onoff == ON) {
        cout << "     Current sensor reading is: " << reading << "\n\n";
    }
    if (onoff == OFF) {
        cout << "     Current reading not available\n\n";
    }
}


//^^^^^^^^^^^^^ANALOG SENSOR^^^^^^^^^//

analogSensor::analogSensor(char *n, float pc, int mn, int mx) : sensor(n, pc) {
    Reading = mn;
    minRead = mn;
    maxRead = mx;
}

void analogSensor::print() {
    sensor::print();
    cout << "     Minimum Value: " << minRead << ".     Maximum Value: " << maxRead;
    if (functioning == WORKING && onoff == ON) {
        cout << "\n     Current sensor reading is: " << Reading << "\n\n";
    }
    if (functioning == WORKING && onoff == OFF) {
        cout << "\n     Current reading not available\n\n";
    }

}
```

You might not need it, but here's (part of) my sensor_node.cpp

```
//Functions in SensorNode
SensorNode::SensorNode(char* n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah)
{
    NodeName = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)+1);
    strcpy(NodeName, n);
    Node1.setx(x);
    Node1.sety(y);
    Node1.setz(z);
    NodeID = i;
    batt = ah;
    func = 1;

}

void SensorNode::print()
{

    cout << "\nSensor node " << NodeName << "\t ID: " << NodeID << "\n Location:  ";
    Node1.print();
    cout << "\n Remaining battery life: " << batt << " amp hours";
    if (func == 0) {
        cout<< "\n Node is not functioning\n";
    }
    if (func == 1) {
        cout <<"\n Node is functioning\n";

    }
}
```

And my sensor_node.h

```
class SensorNode {
    char* NodeName;
    int NodeID;
    LOCATION Node1;
    float batt;
    int func;


public:
    SensorNode(char *n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah);
    void print();
    void setOK(int o);
    int getOK();
    void setLOC(float longi, float lat, float h);
};
```

And Finally, here is my Output!  The issue comes at the end where none of the sensors show names, and the garbage replaces the first two nodes.

Input file:

```
status sensors
status nodes
new_sensor_node  "Kitchen Monitor"   41   1.5  2.5  3.5  10.0
new_sensor_node  Basement   42   3.0   4.0   5.0   5.3
new_sensor  digital  "Window open"   .2
new_sensor  digital  "Oven on"   .5
new_sensor  analog   Temperature  .03  0  255
new_sensor  analog   Humidity  3.1415926  10  20
new_sensor  digital  Alarm   2.0
status nodes
status sensors
new_sensor_node    Garage    51   87.2  93.1   0.0   20.5
new_sensor_node    Attic     52   1.1   2.2   15.3   100.75
new_sensor    digital   G1   1.5
new_sensor    digital   G2   1.5
new_sensor    digital   G3   1.5
new_sensor    digital   G4   1.5
new_sensor    digital   G5   1.5
new_sensor    digital   OOPS1   1.5
new_sensor    analog    OOPS2   1.5   0   31
status sensors
status nodes
new_sensor_node    "Last ok node"    51   87.2  93.1   0.0   20.5
new_sensor_node    "This one should not be added"     52   1.1   2.2   15.3   100.75
halt
```

Output:

```
Number of tokens: 2
Token 1: status
Token 2: sensors
Recognized command "Status"

Number of tokens: 2
Token 1: status
Token 2: nodes
Recognized command "Status"

Number of tokens: 7
Token 1: new_sensor_node
Token 2: Kitchen Monitor
Token 3: 41
Token 4: 1.5
Token 5: 2.5
Token 6: 3.5
Token 7: 10.0
Recognized command "New Sensor Node"

Number of tokens: 7
Token 1: new_sensor_node
Token 2: Basement
Token 3: 42
Token 4: 3.0
Token 5: 4.0
Token 6: 5.0
Token 7: 5.3
Recognized command "New Sensor Node"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: Window open
Token 4: .2
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: Oven on
Token 4: .5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 6
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: analog
Token 3: Temperature
Token 4: .03
Token 5: 0
Token 6: 255
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 6
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: analog
Token 3: Humidity
Token 4: 3.1415926
Token 5: 10
Token 6: 20
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: Alarm
Token 4: 2.0
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 2
Token 1: status
Token 2: nodes

Sensor node Kitchen Monitor  ID: 41
 Location:  (LONGITUDE: 1.5 ,LATITUDE: 2.5 ,HEIGHT: 3.5 )
 Remaining battery life: 10 amp hours
 Node is functioning

Sensor node Basement     ID: 42
 Location:  (LONGITUDE: 3 ,LATITUDE: 4 ,HEIGHT: 5 )
 Remaining battery life: 5.3 amp hours
 Node is functioning
Recognized command "Status"

Number of tokens: 2
Token 1: status
Token 2: sensors
     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 0.2
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 0.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 0.03
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Minimum Value: 0.     Maximum Value: 255
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 3.14159
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Minimum Value: 10.     Maximum Value: 20
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 2
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

Recognized command "Status"

Number of tokens: 7
Token 1: new_sensor_node
Token 2: Garage
Token 3: 51
Token 4: 87.2
Token 5: 93.1
Token 6: 0.0
Token 7: 20.5
Recognized command "New Sensor Node"

Number of tokens: 7
Token 1: new_sensor_node
Token 2: Attic
Token 3: 52
Token 4: 1.1
Token 5: 2.2
Token 6: 15.3
Token 7: 100.75
Recognized command "New Sensor Node"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: G1
Token 4: 1.5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: G2
Token 4: 1.5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: G3
Token 4: 1.5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: G4
Token 4: 1.5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: G5
Token 4: 1.5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 4
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: digital
Token 3: OOPS1
Token 4: 1.5
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 6
Token 1: new_sensor
Token 2: analog
Token 3: OOPS2
Token 4: 1.5
Token 5: 0
Token 6: 31
Recognized command "New Sensor"

Number of tokens: 2
Token 1: status
Token 2: sensors
     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 0.2
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 0.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 0.03
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Minimum Value: 0.     Maximum Value: 255
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 3.14159
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Minimum Value: 10.     Maximum Value: 20
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 2
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Current reading not available

     Sensor:    Power Consumption: 1.5
     Sensor is functioning correctly
     Sensor is Off
     Minimum Value: 0.     Maximum Value: 31
     Current reading not available

Recognized command "Status"

Number of tokens: 2
Token 1: status
Token 2: nodes

Sensor node \200o    ID: 1064672
 Location:  (LONGITUDE: 1.4013e-45 ,LATITUDE: 1.5 ,HEIGHT: 7.00649e-45 )
 Remaining battery life: 3.50325e-44 amp hours
 Node is not functioning

Sensor node \300q    ID: 1064768
 Location:  (LONGITUDE: 1.4013e-45 ,LATITUDE: 1.5 ,HEIGHT: 7.00649e-45 )
 Remaining battery life: 3.50325e-44 amp hours
 Node is not functioning

Sensor node Garage   ID: 51
 Location:  (LONGITUDE: 87.2 ,LATITUDE: 93.1 ,HEIGHT: 0 )
 Remaining battery life: 20.5 amp hours
 Node is functioning

Sensor node Attic    ID: 52
 Location:  (LONGITUDE: 1.1 ,LATITUDE: 2.2 ,HEIGHT: 15.3 )
 Remaining battery life: 100.75 amp hours
 Node is functioning
Recognized command "Status"

Number of tokens: 7
Token 1: new_sensor_node
Token 2: Last ok node
Token 3: 51
Token 4: 87.2
Token 5: 93.1
Token 6: 0.0
Token 7: 20.5
Recognized command "New Sensor Node"

Number of tokens: 7
Token 1: new_sensor_node
Token 2: This one should not be added
Token 3: 52
Token 4: 1.1
Token 5: 2.2
Token 6: 15.3
Token 7: 100.75
Recognized command "New Sensor Node"

Number of tokens: 1
Token 1: halt
Recognized command "Halt"
```

As always, thanks for any help that can be offered!  Sorry about the tons of code.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see what the results of these operations are?

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), by the way. I also recommend never using `new`, except until C++14 when making a `std::unique_ptr`, or unless you actually have a good reason to. Using it instead of smart pointers or containers just because is not.

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem with fewer lines of code. The process of doing so will help you pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Yea, I've stepped through with a debugger, and it's very strange.  The token array shows the correct token, and I use that token, but the name just comes up as '\0'.

Comment: SensorList[numSensors] = new digitalSensor(token[2],convertFloatToValue(token[3]));  is where the name (token[2]) is assigned as the name member variable for the sensor.  But for some reason the name is made '\0'

Comment: I solved one issue!  I added the line strcpy(SensorName, n); after my malloc in my sensor initialization.  I was allocating the space, but not actually assigning the argument to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved one issue! I added the line strcpy(SensorName, n); after my malloc in my sensor initialization. I was allocating the space, but not actually assigning the argument to it